# Linphone Xamarin.iOS sample app with NuGET package build issue

Tags: ios, xamarin, linphone

I am trying to use the Linphone Xamarin sample app with their self-hosted NuGet package (LinphoneSDK.Xamarin version 5.2.8) I have it working with Android, but for iOS, after removing the native package assemblies and adding the NuGET package to the project, I get errors when trying to build the project. I think these are the relevant lines from the build output:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -stdlib=libc++ -gdwarf-2 -std=c++14 -I/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.2.sdk -Qunused-arguments -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -arch x86_64 -c -o /Users/user/Documents/linphone-xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/x86_64/main.o -x objective-c++ -D MONOTOUCH -D DEBUG /Users/user/Documents/linphone-xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/x86_64/main.m
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -framework CoreFoundation -framework Security -framework CFNetwork -framework QuickLook -framework SceneKit -framework OpenGLES -framework MediaPlayer -framework ImageIO -framework GLKit -framework WebKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreText -framework CoreSpotlight -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework QuartzCore -framework CloudKit -framework UIKit -framework GSS -weak_framework Intents -weak_framework linphone /Users/user/Documents/linphone-xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/x86_64/main.o /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.a /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/lib/libxamarin-debug.a /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/lib/libmono-native-compat.a -force_load /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/lib/libapp.a -Wl,-pie -arch x86_64 -gdwarf-2 -std=c++14 -I/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.2.sdk -Qunused-arguments -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -lz -liconv -lz -o /Users/user/Documents/linphone-xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/LinphoneXamarin.iOS.app/LinphoneXamarin.iOS -u _SystemNative_ConvertErrorPlatformToPal -u _SystemNative_ConvertErrorPalToPlatform -u _SystemNative_StrErrorR -u _SystemNative_GetNonCryptographicallySecureRandomBytes -u _SystemNative_GetReadDirRBufferSize -u _SystemNative_ReadLink -u _SystemNative_Stat2 -u _SystemNative_LStat2 -u _SystemNative_Symlink -u _SystemNative_CopyFile -u _SystemNative_GetEGid -u _SystemNative_GetEUid -u _SystemNative_Link -u _SystemNative_MkDir -u _SystemNative_Rename -u _SystemNative_Unlink -u _SystemNative_OpenDir -u _SystemNative_ReadDirR -u _SystemNative_CloseDir -u _xamarin_timezone_get_local_name -u _xamarin_timezone_get_data -u _xamarin_GetFolderPath -u _xamarin_log -u _NetSecurityNative_ReleaseGssBuffer -u _NetSecurityNative_DisplayMinorStatus -u _NetSecurityNative_DisplayMajorStatus -u _NetSecurityNative_ImportUserName -u _NetSecurityNative_ImportPrincipalName -u _NetSecurityNative_ReleaseName -u _NetSecurityNative_InitiateCredSpNego -u _NetSecurityNative_InitiateCredWithPassword -u _NetSecurityNative_ReleaseCred -u _NetSecurityNative_InitSecContext -u _NetSecurityNative_DeleteSecContext -u _xamarin_start_wwan -u _xamarin_release_managed_ref -u _xamarin_set_gchandle_with_flags_safe -u _xamarin_UIApplicationMain -u _xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type -u _xamarin_release_block_on_main_thread -u _xamarin_get_block_descriptor -u _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_exception -u _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_exception -u _mono_pmip -u _xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend -u _xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSendSuper -u _xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend_stret -u _xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSendSuper_stret
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -framework CoreFoundation -framework Security -framework CFNetwork -framework QuickLook -framework SceneKit -framework OpenGLES -framework MediaPlayer -framework ImageIO -framework GLKit -framework WebKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreText -framework CoreSpotlight -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreData -framework QuartzCore -framework CloudKit -framework UIKit -framework GSS -weak_framework Intents -weak_framework linphone /Users/user/Documents/linphone-xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/mtouch-cache/x86_64/main.o /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.a /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/lib/libxamarin-debug.a /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/lib/libmono-native-compat.a -force_load /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/lib/libapp.a -Wl,-pie -arch x86_64 -gdwarf-2 -std=c++14 -I/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/16.1.1.27/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/include -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator16.2.sdk -Qunused-arguments -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -lz -liconv -lz -o /Users/user/Documents/linphone-xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin/Xamarin.iOS/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/LinphoneXamarin.iOS.app/LinphoneXamarin.iOS -u _SystemNative_ConvertErrorPlatformToPal -u _SystemNative_ConvertErrorPalToPlatform -u _SystemNative_StrErrorR -u _SystemNative_GetNonCryptographicallySecureRandomBytes -u _SystemNative_GetReadDirRBufferSize -u _SystemNative_ReadLink -u _SystemNative_Stat2 -u _SystemNative_LStat2 -u _SystemNative_Symlink -u _SystemNative_CopyFile -u _SystemNative_GetEGid -u _SystemNative_GetEUid -u _SystemNative_Link -u _SystemNative_MkDir -u _SystemNative_Rename -u _SystemNative_Unlink -u _SystemNative_OpenDir -u _SystemNative_ReadDirR -u _SystemNative_CloseDir -u _xamarin_timezone_get_local_name -u _xamarin_timezone_get_data -u _xamarin_GetFolderPath -u _xamarin_log -u _NetSecurityNative_ReleaseGssBuffer -u _NetSecurityNative_DisplayMinorStatus -u _NetSecurityNative_DisplayMajorStatus -u _NetSecurityNative_ImportUserName -u _NetSecurityNative_ImportPrincipalName -u _NetSecurityNative_ReleaseName -u _NetSecurityNative_InitiateCredSpNego -u _NetSecurityNative_InitiateCredWithPassword -u _NetSecurityNative_ReleaseCred -u _NetSecurityNative_InitSecContext -u _NetSecurityNative_DeleteSecContext -u _xamarin_start_wwan -u _xamarin_release_managed_ref -u _xamarin_set_gchandle_with_flags_safe -u _xamarin_UIApplicationMain -u _xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type -u _xamarin_release_block_on_main_thread -u _xamarin_get_block_descriptor -u _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_exception -u _xamarin_IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_exception -u _mono_pmip -u _xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend -u _xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSendSuper -u _xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSend_stret -u _xamarin_dyn_objc_msgSendSuper_stret
ld: framework not found linphone
clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
...
clang : error : linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error MT5209 : Native linking error : framework not found linphone
MTOUCH : error MT5202: Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
3 Warning(s)
3 Error(s)
```

I tried setting the Linker behaviour to 'Don't Link' and it built, but when I ran the app on the iPhone simulator, I received this exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: linphone.framework/linphone assembly: type: member:(null)

Anyone know how to get this project to run?